# Different execution plan for identical query

Tags: postgresql-performance

Below queries result in completely different execution plans in PostgreSQL 14. For Oracle both queries are identical.

```
SELECT *
FROM sa   
JOIN sched
    ON sa.DATE_STR = sched.DATE_STR   
    AND sa.DATE_STR >= '2024-03-31'
    AND sa.DATE_STR <= '2024-04-03'
;

SELECT *
FROM sa   
JOIN sched
    ON sa.DATE_STR = sched.DATE_STR   
    AND sched.DATE_STR >= '2024-03-31'
    AND sched.DATE_STR <= '2024-04-03'
;
```

Can anybody explain why they are different for PostgreSQL and if there is a setting to make them identical.

Comment: Are there relevant statistics on both sa and sched? Index on DATE_STR for both tables?

Comment: In this article (althogh a couple of years old) the author compares how good various DBMS is at query rewriting using algebraic rules: https://blog.jooq.org/10-cool-sql-optimisations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-cost-model/  You may find something in there as an explanation to why your version of postgres can't infer the date interval between tables despite the equality predicate

Comment: Well what *are* the query plans?